# Continuous Deployment of .net core using Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins, aws-lambda, continuous-deployment, dotnetzip

I have a dot net project with microservices deployed at Lambda Function. I want  Continuous Deployment for this project.

Currently I am using a Jenkins Server that is building the project successfully. Now what can I do to zip the build and push it to the lambda function? I'm stuck at zipping the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [File Operations Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/File+Operations+Plugin) or [Compress Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Compress+Artifacts+Plugin) to create a zip archive in Jenkins job.